# Editing a record by accessing it

Tags: entity-framework, linq, azure-functions

I am updating a database register but before updating I fetched the same register.

Because of that I receive the following error:

> The instance of entity type 'Position' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being
>   tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
>   instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

This is the code:

```
            [FunctionName(nameof(PostUpdatePosition))]
            public ActionResult PostUpdatePosition([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "postUpdatePosition")]HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                PositionViewModel viewModel;

                try
                {
                    // Received json 
                    viewModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request
                                    .Content
                                    .ReadAsStringAsync()
                                    .Result);

                    var clientId = positonRepository.GetById(viewModel.Id).ClientId;

                    // here the error appears. ▼
                    positonRepository.Update(new Domain.Entities.Position
                    {
                        Id = viewModel.Id,
                        Description = viewModel.Description,
                        Active = viewModel.Active,
                        ClientId = clientId
                    });

                    positonRepository.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                        new EasyEpiJson()
                        .GetInternalServerError(ex));
                }

                return Ok(new EasyEpiJson().GetOK(viewModel));
            }
        }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are creating your own problems here.  Just get rid of positionRepository and use your DbContext subtype directly in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update a position that has not been tracked by EF. Instead, first retrieve the object you want to update, update the fields and finish by passing that object to your repository:

```
            var position = positonRepository.GetById(viewModel.Id);

            position.Description = viewModel.Description;
            position.Active = viewModel.Active;

            positonRepository.Update(position);
            positonRepository.SaveChanges();
```